# ControlTemplate for DataGridCell

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate, wpf-4.0, contentpresenter

I am working on a **Data Virtualization** solution provided by ***Bea Stollnitz*** on her [blog](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/378). This solution is provided to work with a `ListView`. I am just trying to make it work with **WPF** `DataGrid` but I am not successful in my attempt.

[Here](http://www.zagstudio.com/blogfiles/comments/57DataVirtualizationPer.zip) is the code for the full working example provided by her.

The `ListView` in the provided code is bound to an custom `AsyncVirtualizingCollection` collection `class`. But when I try to bind this collection to the **DataGrid**, it does display blank rows. The data does not appear in the `DataGrid`.

Now the magic happens in the way the `ControlTemplate` is written for the `ListViewItem`. I have zeroed it down to the `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate`. The `ContentPresenter` has been replaced with a `Border` behaving as the `ContentPresenter`. Following is **XAML** for the same:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border Name="InnerBorder" CornerRadius="1" BorderThickness="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="11"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Name="UpperHighlight" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="#75FFFFFF"/>
                            <GridViewRowPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                    Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Data}"/>
                            <StackPanel Name="Loading" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <TextBlock Text="Loading item " />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemNumber}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="..." />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now, on having a close look at the `GridViewRowPresenter` in the `Grid` inside the second border, you might notice: `Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Data}"`

I think this is the line that helps in displaying data.

I tried creating a `ControlTemplate` for the `DataGridCell` as following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" 
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Data}" 
                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but I still do not get any data in the `DataGrid`.

I am not sure what I am missing here as I am not good with templates and styles.

I tried to keep this as precise as possible in order to avoid making it too boring. I you think I have missed out any information please do ask, I would be more than happy to provide that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The linked application targets .Net 3.5 and would need to converted for .Net 4.0 to be able to use DataGrid.

Comment: does your item  contain property Data in it?

Comment: I am not sure as to what your question is. But just for explanation, AsyncVirtualizingCollection<T> inherits VirtualizingCollection<T> which in turn implements IList<DataWrapper<T>> and this DataWrapper class contains the 'Data' Property. I know it's complicated but it's what I got. I could not find a simpler solution for Data Virtualization.

Comment: are you getting the rows with blank values? or you are not even getting rows?

Comment: I am getting rows with blank values. The rows get created but the data does not display. :(

Comment: If you are using the attached example application, you would need to just add the following code: `<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Name="dg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Height="300" Width="400">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>`

Comment: Also, you would need to add the ControlTemplate that I have provided in the question.

Comment: can you test you sol by removing ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"

Comment: I tried. Still I get blank rows. Are you getting the datagrid to show data in your testing? :(

Comment: how are you binding your DataGrid columns..can you share?

Comment: I did share in the comment above. In the grey code. That's my datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `DataWrapper` is the item for your `DataGrid` which is wraping the actual item in `Data` Property, you should update your column binding like:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                       IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Name="dg"  
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Height="300" Width="400"> 
     <DataGrid.Columns> 
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Data.Id}" Width="100"/>  
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Data.Name}" Width="100"/>  
     </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

Similarly you will have to set the binding in your ControlTemplate like:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne. I didn't even take notice of the binding. I was only looking at the ContentPresenter.